# jquery - Change element attribute when image source changes

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I'm using the Nivo Slider Plugin that works in conjunction with the NextGen Gallery. What I'm trying to do is get the image source and rewrite a url when the image changes. I currently have this:

```
$(function() {
    var src = $('.nivo-main-image').attr('src');
    $("#social-buttons > #pinterest").attr('href', src);
});
```

It works on page load and gets the source of whatever image appears first and does almost exactly what I need it to do. However, I need it to change the href attribute whenever the image source changes in the slideshow. I looked into `.change()`, but that only works for various inputs.

Can anyone help with this, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.nivo-main-image', function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#social-buttons > #pinterest").attr('href', src);
});
```

**Edit, see comments below:**

I added the following to the `jquery.nivo.slider.js` file at line 209:

```
var src = $('.nivo-main-image').attr('src');
$("#social-buttons > #pinterest").attr('href', src);
```

It works perfectly now. (until the plugin gets updated
)

Comment: When I use this, nothing happens and I don't get any errors either. I read on jquery.com that the change even only works with form fields. Any recommendations?

Comment: Interesting. I normally use this code with on('click') events and its great. I'd try to find the piece of code that is changing the images and append the code to that function, so it'll run every time the image changes and also update the hrefs.

Comment: That's what I was just looking into. I found a function in nivo's core files that runs after every image change. I added lines 2 and 3 from the above code and it works. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nivo-main-image').attr('src').change(function(){
    var src = $('.nivo-main-image').attr('src');
    $("#social-buttons > #pinterest").attr('href', src);
})
```

Comment: It seems to break the slider all together.